# Import JSON into VueJS

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I'm using wbepack to compile a VUEJS project in which I import a JSON file which has an array of objects into vueJS however when accessing it via the component the object appears to be empty.

```
import Jason from './some.json';
export defaults {
data(){ return { someArr: Jason } } }
```

I'm not getting any compile errors or any other reported errors.

What could cause the object `someArr` to be empty?

*P.S. I am able to load the json via AJAX successfully*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to SCR and find a file named shims-vue.d.ts and add a JSON module like this.

```
    declare module '*.json' 
{
  const value: { [key: string]: any };
  export default value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Install json loader with

```
npm install json-loader --save
```

then in your webpack.config file add this loader

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.json/,
            loader: 'json',
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: *"Since webpack >= v2.0.0, importing of JSON files will work by default. You might still want to use this if you use a custom file extension. See the v1.0.0 -> v2.0.0 Migration Guide for more information"* extract from the [Webpack Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/).

Comment: Note, since Webpack 4, `loaders` is now `rules`.

Answer (score 1):

probably just a typo but you `export default {` not `defaults`

Assuming this isn't an issue are you exporting the JSON within `./some.json`? i.e.

```
export default {
  "foo": "bar",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

In *main.js*:

```
import Conf from './static/app-conf.json';
Vue.prototype.$appConfig = Conf;
```

Now I can use that JSON-file whereever I need it by adding it to data:

```
    <template>
      <div>{{someText}}</div>
    </template>
    <script>        
        export default {
                name: 'Something',
                components: {},
                props: {},
                data: () => ({
                    someText: Vue.prototype.$appConfig.someText,
                }),
                computed: {},
                methods: {}
            };
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
var yourJSONData= JSON.parse(Jason);
```